# JQuery ajax GET request, success not firing while response status is 200 OK

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, rest

I am having a weird response with JSON response data while sending a REST call . I can see in firebug that response status is ok, but the body is empty, even though trying with poster it works fine. Here is my JQuery call:

```
var urlPath = "http://localhost:8080/coreserver/rest";

function totalAccountCount()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlPath + "/summary/totalAccountCount",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (resp) {
           var rowText = "<tr><td>Total Accounts</td><td>" + resp.wrapper.item + "</td></tr>";
           $(rowText).appendTo(tbody);
           //loadCustomers(resp); 
           alert("STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){  
             alert("Error: fails"); 
             //$("#message").html(resp.e  + " - STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

           } 
    });
}
```

While debugging it, it does not go to the success branch, but the error one. Here is my Resource:

```
@GET
@Path("/totalAccountCount")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public JaxbWrapper<Integer> getTotalAccountCount() {
    return new JaxbWrapper<Integer>((int)this.accountStore.count());
}
```

I already know that reading my response with the `JaxbWrapper` is probably wrong, but is not hitting success at all, so for now I want to make sure this works.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: as of jQuery 1.9 when using `dataType:'json'` if server response is empty it is not treated as success.

Comment: I am currently using jquery-1.8.3: status is ok 200 but not going into success in fact

Comment: is this a cross domain request? If so can get a 200 but if not CORS enabled or setup for jsonp will not trigger success

Comment: no it's localhost, all on the same domain. Moreover it works with poster when I try to call it from the browser returning the value but as an XML not JSON I don't know if that could be the issue?

Comment: Try to compare both the raw request i.e. when action performed from your jquery and when performed from browser. Also try setting the content-type from your jquery call.

Comment: added content type but same. Also, here is the response I get from the browser <wrapper><item xsi:type="xs:int">3</item></wrapper>

Comment: Try changing your method to this `public Response getTotalAccountCount(){ return Response.ok().entity("okay").build();}` and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

async: false solved it. It was jumping all the time to error function and then success

**Update 1**

the real reason for getting it to work is because I added the following in my web.xml on the server side:

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

anyone can relate to this?

**Update 2**

It was just cached. problem solved.

Thanks,

Comment: That is not a fix, you will create more problems this way. Problems like page freeze, browser crush and so on.

Comment: you are right, it works even without. It confused me because it simply matched another change I've done on the server side in the same time. I will update my answer.